# How to mark Google Calendar Goal event as done using the api?

Tags: api, google-api, google-calendar-api

As the question says, I can't find any documentation on Google Apis about [the Goal feature in Google Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6334090?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=). Right now I'm using javascript for my api but haven't started writing code for this yet since I can't find any endpoints.

I'm looking at the [event update endpoint](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) but there doesn't seem to be a done property.

Comment: This feature does not exist in the API. try adding a feature request if there isnt already one https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B